# How to resolve the following error? scan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Tags: python, embedded, can-bus

I used the following commands in SocketCAN and I used the CANtact toolkit as a serial bus interface. ALL the commands work fine except the last command. It throws the following error:

```
scan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.
```

OS-Ubuntu 18.04.1

`sudo modprobe can`

`sudo modprobe can_raw`

`sudo modprobe slcan`

`slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyACM0 slcan0`

`ifconfig slcan0 up`

[image: This the output i get when i give ifconfig]

Comment: what's the output of `ifconfig`? could you show us the output, please

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of ifconfig output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root permission to execute the last two commands you wrote in your post:

`sudo slcand -o -s6 -t hw -S 3000000 /dev/ttyACM0 slcan0`

`sudo ifconfig slcan0 up`

Then it works.